# How would I put all the ID values from this dictionary into a list?

Tags: python

Basically, I want to return all the "ID" values from this JSON data and put them into a list:

https://www.roblox.com/games/getgameinstancesjson?placeId=70501379&startindex=0

Here's the code I have so far. It returns all the JSON data from above and puts it into a dictionary. The problem is, I am absolutely lost on how to progress into the dictionary and get the ID values. 'Tis a monster. Please help.

```
import urllib, json

url = "https://www.roblox.com/games/getgameinstancesjson?
placeId=70501379&startindex=0"

response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())
```

Comment: Also, here's an annotated example of the IDs I want to put into a list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5B9I.jpg

Comment: Please include a fragment of the json in the actual questions - screenshots of text are discouraged here because links tend to die over time.

Comment: Well you got the JSON data, but you did not try to solve the problem yet.

Comment: The JSON contains a number of "collections", each containing a number of 
players: did you want a single list of player IDs across all collections, or separate lists per collection?

Comment: I want a single list of player IDs across all collections please, thanks Mac. And Klaus, I've tried sorting it in a bunch of different ways, I just didn't include that code.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you're trying to accumulate the IDs of all the current players.

```
ids = []
for entry in data['Collection']:
    ids.extend(player['Id'] for player in entry['CurrentPlayers'])
```

Comment: So to my understanding, CurrentPlayers was under Collection, and player was in CurrentPlayers, and ID was contained in that?

Comment: Thank you so much by the way.

Comment: That's what it looked like from what you shared about the API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the JSON data structure to collect all the ids.

```
 import urllib, json

url = "https://www.roblox.com/games/getgameinstancesjson?placeId=70501379&startindex=0"

response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())
ids = []
for i in data["Collection"][0]["CurrentPlayers"]:
    ids.append(i["Id"])
print ids
```

Answer (score 0):

These current players are shared among 7 collections in total, Here is the explicit version of @wiludsdaman's answer

```
ids = []
for collection in data["Collection"]:
    for player in collection["CurrentPlayers"]:
        ids.append(player["Id"])

print ids
```

If you are braver, You can deflate the above code using double list comprehension

```
ids = [player["Id"] for collection in data["Collection"] for player in collection["CurrentPlayers"]]
```

Comment: Our solutions are identical. `mylist.extend(iterable)` is equivalent to `for e in iterable: mylist.append(e)`.